# How to perform reverse of string in jsp?

Tags: string, jsp, reverse

This is my demo.jsp code ,here i'm writing code as follow,result showing as No line found exception where as i executed the code in java class working fine.How can i execute the revers e of string in jsp page?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String :");
        String n = sc.nextLine();
        String rev = "";
        int len = n.length();
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            rev = rev + n.charAt(i);
        }
        out.println("Reverse of Given String is :");
        out.println("" + rev);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code works without errors . i guess the problem is you are passing the empty string as the input to `nextLine` method,

Try passing the values like this ,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String :");
        String n = sc.nextLine();
        String rev = "value";
        int len = n.length();
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            rev = rev + n.charAt(i);
        }
        out.println("Reverse of Given String is :");
        out.println("" + rev)
```

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

The above code is pure Java code, not a valid JSP code. If we split what the above code does, it

1. Prompt for user input.
2. Perform the reverse on user entered string.
3. Print the result string.

`System.in` and `Scanner` cannot be used to read user input from a JSP page. Fundamentally the user interaction results in communication between the client (browser) and the server (like Tomcat).

In simple the below code is what makes your code a JSP.

Note : The jsp file name and the value of `form` `action` must be same.

```
<body>
    <form action="rev.jsp">
    <!--  1. Prompt for user input -->
    Enter Text : <input type="text" name="myText"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Text"/>
    <br/>

    <%
        // 2. Perform the reverse on user entered string.
        String rev = "";
        String n = request.getParameter("myText"); // read user entered value in text box.
        if(n != null) { // if myText is entered 
            int len = n.length();
            for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                rev = rev + n.charAt(i);
            }
            // 3. Print the result string.
            out.println("Reverse of Given String is :");
            out.println("" + rev);
        }
    %>
   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open already existing function, You can use following,

```
String reverse = new StringBuffer(words).reverse().toString();
```

Refer [THIS](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-reverse-a-string-words-or-sentences/)